# Nothing is getting displayed on JFrame

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

This what I am doing but is nothing is getting displayed on Jframe window. I have not extended class JFrame to do my, is it necessary to do so for displaying objects on window.

```
public class testGraphics {
    static JFrame workingFrame = null;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame workingManager = new JFrame("Hello");
        workingManager.setSize(500, 500);
        workingManager.setVisible(true);
        Graphics g = workingManager.getGraphics();
        JPanel jp = (JPanel) workingManager.getContentPane();
        workingManager.paintComponents(g);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
        g.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the frame visible at the end.

Comment: Also, try doing this all on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: setting visible at the end gives nullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* ever call `getGraphics()` or explicitly call `paintXxx()` to do custom painting.  The correct way to do custom painting is to override the `paintComponent` method of the panel to paint on. The overriden method will be implicitly called *for* you. Then add that panel to the frame. Also you should override the `getPreferredSize()` of the panel, so it has a preferred size, so you can just pack the frame

```
class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected paintComponent(Grapchics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(....);
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {'
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}
```

Then add it to the frame (or if you want to set it as the content pane of the frame, do that instead)

```
PaintPanel panel = new PaintPaint();
frame.add(panel);
...
frame.pack();
```

See more at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: For one, you won't know when the component needs to be repainted and the contents will be over painted without your knowledge

Comment: Also note, a non-null Graphics object is only available after the component has been rendered. Even so, any repaints will not persist. So don't use this way to paint.

Comment: what you mean to say is, repaint is persisting so, I am not able to see any thing

Comment: I meant the Graphics object will not persist to any repaints.

Answer (score 1):

I made several changes to your code to get it to work properly.

1. I changed your main method to call the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to make sure that the Swing components were defined and used on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
2. I created a drawing JPanel.  I set the color first, then drew the ovals.
3. I added a JFrame default close operation.  You must specify a default close operation, or else your Java application will continue running after you close the JFrame.
4. I moved the size to the drawing panel.  The frame size will be calculated when you call the JFrame pack method.

And here's the modified code:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGraphics implements Runnable{

    private JFrame workingManager;

    private JPanel drawingPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        workingManager = new JFrame("Hello");
        workingManager.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();

        workingManager.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        workingManager.pack();
        workingManager.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        workingManager.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestGraphics());
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 
                -3701718376300985046L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
            g.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setSize()` and `setVisible()` must be at the bottom of the method:

```
 JFrame workingManager = new JFrame("Hello");
    Graphics g = workingManager.getGraphics();
    JPanel jp = (JPanel) workingManager.getContentPane();
    workingManager.paintComponents(g);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
    g.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);
    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);

    workingManager.setSize(500, 500);
    workingManager.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @user3709980 this means you haven't initialize the workingManager instance

Comment: actually I am new in this, I guess the workingManager is already initialized as you can see here

Comment: Using `getGraphics()` on the frame before the frame has been rendered (setVisible), will return a null `Graphics` object. Does not have to do with initializing of the frame. In any case, `getGraphics()` is not the correct way to perform custom painting.